# Align text on the top border of an image

Tags: css, image, text

Good day,

This is what I have: http://postimg.org/image/n0i0671ul/

This is what I want to achieve:http://postimg.org/image/4ql3bdq2z/

I have wrapped the flags and floated them to the right, then I have set in the style css to float each image to the left(so the order will be kept properly). I would like to add text-boxes on top of my images however, I can't really achieve this. Can anyone give me some tips on this?

```
#flagLine {
   float: right;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#flagLine a img {

    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;

}

#flagLine h4 {
    vertical-align: top;
}

<div id="flagLine">
  <a href="https://internal.cs.ncl.ac.uk/modules/2013-14/csc1026/flags/letters/100_ICS_Alpha.svg.png"><img src="1.png" title='"I have a diver down; keep well clear at slow speed."' /></a><h4>A-Alpha</h4>
  <a href="https://internal.cs.ncl.ac.uk/modules/2013-14/csc1026/flags/letters/100_ICS_Bravo.svg.png"><img src="2.png" title='"I am taking in, or discharging, or carrying dangerous goods."'/></a><h4>B-Bravo</h4>
 <a href="https://internal.cs.ncl.ac.uk/modules/2013-14/csc1026/flags/letters/100_ICS_Charlie.svg.png"><img src="3.png" title='"Affirmative."'/></a>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please post your code (html and css) so we can help you

Comment: And where is the code? That's the question.

Comment: Please show us the HTML & CSS code you have tried and are having trouble with.

Comment: I have added code as requested guyis, sorry for my newbie formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

You are floating only the images left, this creates the wrong layout.

**Solution :**

You need to wrap the images with the titles in a `div` and float that `div` left.
This will leed your images and titles to stay together and float together.

Example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BB8mv/8/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p>Flag Name</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <p>Flag Name</p>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
</div>
...
```

CSS :

```
.wrap {
    float:left;
}
.wrap img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) with the code you made, beause with the image I can only try to guess between many possible issues.

Comment: Sure mate: 

https://dpaste.de/QHhA

As you can see here, I have floated both: the images and the text to the left so I made sure they will stay together.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This won't work. You need to change the `html` markup (as I said in my answer) --> wrap both image and title in a `div` and float taht `div` left (you will also need to remove `float:left;` on both image and title

Comment: Just one second, I will try this out!

Comment: Thank you very much mate, that has worked! Sorry for such questions, I am new to web design!